# How to configure wifi in lenovo G50-70

Tags: 14.04

I have Lenovo G50-70 model laptop  i have installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS wired network is working but wifi not how do i get wifi network?

Comment: Open terminal Ctrl+Alt+t, run `sudo lshw -c network` , add its output the the question.

Answer (score 1):

This laptop has no hardware wifi switch. Kernel module ideapad-laptop does not treat it right. That is why wireless is always blocked by rfkill. This has been reported upstream. For current users this can be fixed by installung a patched module from ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/ideapad-laptop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ideapad-laptop
```

Note for 14.04 users:

The module is built for Ubuntu 14.04.2 with 3.16 kernel. I did not test it with earlier kernels.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called `ideapad_laptop` that prevents the `wifi` module to start.

1) blacklist this with:

```
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
```

2) Prevents the `WiFi` card from automatically sleeping and halting connection

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Answer (score -2):

To install Broadcom wifi drivers OFFLINE

1. Insert the install disk/USB Stick
2. Browse to `/pool/main/e/eglibc`
3. Click on: `libc-dev-bin_2.19-0ubuntu6.3_amd64.deb` and after that installs,
4. Click on: `libc6-dev_2.19-0ubuntu6.3_amd64.deb` after that installs...
5. Browse the disk to: `/main/b/bcmwl`
6. Install `bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb`
7. You should now have WiFi.